# Variable method not to repeat myself for: document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm looking for a method where I can make a variable containing the `document.getElementById` and include the correct value for the ID as a variable value. What I have now is this:

```
    let lenght = parseInt(document.getElementById("lenght").value);
    let start = parseInt(document.getElementById("start").value);
    let end = parseInt(document.getElementById("end").value);
```

But what I would like to have is something like this:

```
    let documentById = parseInt(document.getElementById($elementName).value)
    let lenght = documentById("lenght");
    let start = documentById("start");
    let end = documentById("end");
```

Am I thinking in the correct way or is this a method that does not make sense? Any tips/suggestions are welcome as I try to learn.

Comment: Yes, just make sure to make `documentById` a function using `documentById = ($elementName) => …`

Comment: When using `parseInt` be sure to specify the `radix` parameter, otherwise leading zeroes in the string will cause it to be parsed as octal, not decimal (alternatively use the `new Number(text)` constructor. Also you need to check for `isNaN`.

Comment: It's spelled `length` not `lenght` btw.

Comment: Your proposed `documentById` function needs a different name. Consider `getElementValueById`.

Comment: Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of `parseInt`, or, specifically for `<input>`s, [`.valueAsNumber`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties). Then the code can be shortened as `const [ length, start, end ] = [ "length", "start", "end" ].map((id) => document.getElementById(id).valueAsNumber);`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks, I got it like this now: function `dataOphalen(naam) {
  return parseInt(document.getElementById(naam).value);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with a simple function that takes in the ID of the element as a parameter and returns the value as intended

```js
function documentById(id) {
  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!el) return undefined; // element doesn't exist 
  const value = parseInt(el.value, 10); // parsing string to a number (default radix is 10)
  return isNaN(value) ? { number: false, value: value } : { number: true, value: value }; 
}

const { number, value } = documentById('end'); // if value isnt a number return false (to prevent errors);
if (number) console.log(value); // if value is a number log its value
else console.log('not a valid number')
```

Comment: Don't forget `parseInt`'s `radix` parameter _and_ to check for `isNaN`.

Comment: yea thanks ill edit

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can make a function that returns just that.

```js
const getValueById = (id) => parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value, 10);

const length = getValueById("length");
const start = getValueById("start");
const end = getValueById("end");

console.log({ length, start, end });
```

```html
<input id="length" value="5" />
<input id="start" value="2" />
<input id="end" value="6" />
```